# Sharepoint ID search in PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint

I have one List Screen in which my items have the ID in Sharepoint as a Subtitle. I want to search by all: Title, Subtitle and Body. The problem is that when I try to search by the ID everything goes blank.

I've used this function:

```
Search(my_SP_List, TextSearchBox1.Text, "a", "b", "ID")
```

The thing is that when I have the formula like this `Search(my_SP_List, TextSearchBox1.Text, "a", "b")` it works, but not with the ID from Sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

This is from their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup): "The Search function finds records in a table that contain a string in one of their columns." ID probably is not a string